# getattr(sys, 'frozen', False) problem in 2 different packaged executables

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pyinstaller

I am new to converting python scripts into executables and chanced upon Pyinstaller.

I have a script (Script #1) that using Python2.7 and managed to package the script using the codes `pyinstaller test.py --onefile --name test_exe` & `pyinstaller test_exe.spec --onefile --name test_exe`

Here is the part of the script (Script #1) that has getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):

```
import sys

def add_config(): 
  print("[+] Entered Add_config")
    try:
        if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
            <some code..>

            print("[+] Version:")
            print(<some code>)
            print("[+] Serial:")
            print(<some code>)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   print("[+] Entered Main")
   add_config()
```

However, when I executed the executable that has Script #1, this was the output:

```
[+] Entered Main
[+] Entered Add_config
<Program Exits>
```

I tried creating another packaged executable with the script helloWorld.py and used the same codes `pyinstaller helloWorld.py --onefile --name helloWorld_test` & `pyinstaller helloWorld_test.spec --onefile --name helloWorld_test`

Here are the contents of helloWorld.py:

```
 import sys

 print("Hello There")

 if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
   print("Script is packaged as executable")
 else:
   print("Script is running as a script")
```

Here is the output of the executable with helloWorld.py:

> Hello There
>
> Script is packaged as executable

Does anyone know why the first script (Script #1) does not enter the if condition of `getattr(sys, 'frozen', False)` when it is clearly running as an executable?

Some other context:

- Pyinstaller version: 3.6
- Python version: Python 2.7.16
- Product Name:Mac OS X
- ProductVersion : 10.15.7
- BuildVersion: 19H15

**EDIT:**
Thanks to the comments, I found out that I was receiving an error within the  and the original function `getattr(sys, 'frozen', False)` works fine.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't going down that path in script #1? Maybe something is failing quietly in the "<some code...>" section, because it's in a try. Try printing directly after entering the block.

Comment: Do not wrap multiple lines that potentially raise errors within a single try/except block. As `getattr(sys, 'frozen', False)` won't raise any error, use it outside try/except.

Answer (score 0):

By doing `if getattr(sys, "frozen", False)` you are not first checking if the system actually has an attribute called 'frozen'. If you add a `print(hasattr(sys, "frozen"))` you will see that it returns false, hence the condition inside the try will be false, exiting your program without printing the Version and Serial lines.

If you change the condition to `if hasattr(sys, "frozen") is False:` you will check to see if the system has this attribute in the first place, and if it doesnt, print your Verison and Serial lines.

Comment: Hi @LittleBigTech, thank you so much for your answer! Unfortunately, the author of Script #1 is not me so I would prefer not to change the original code. However, I will heed your advice in using `hasattr` instead of `getattr` for my future coding!